# Search in gvim ignoring special characters

Tags: vim

How do I search for a string in gvim ignoring all special/regex characters in it ?

Something like:

`/<It doesn't matter what is here>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start your search string with `\V` to turn off regex searching:

```
/\V<It doesn't matter what is here>
```

This is very nomagic mode (the opposite of very magic mode). See `:h \V`.

Just note that you still need to escape `\` with `\\`.

Comment: @FDinoff That's not true, and you can verify this by turning on `hlsearch` and trying search patterns with `\V` at the beginning, and at the end.  I think this is documented, but I can't find the exact reference right now.

Comment: @FDinoff The exact verse from the manual: _Use of "\V" means that in the pattern after it only the backslash has a special meaning._  Only to the pattern after `\V` is turned "very nomagic".

Comment: @lcd047 interesting... I could have sworn I've use `\v` after the fact for the whole pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Search with `?search_without_need_to_escape_slash`

Ref: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_without_need_to_escape_slash